# Windows Phone 8.1 WebView based app: how can I modify the text size of natively displayed items of an HTML <select>?

Tags: html, list, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 WebView based application.
In one HTML pages I have a  object with some  inside.

When I launch the application and tap on the combobox a native list of items (taken from the  objects) is displayed.

I need to change the size of the text for those items in the list, how can I do it?

To replicate this you can just create an HTML5 app in Visul Studio and edit index.html file adding a  object, then launch the application and tap on the combobox.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** here is the code...

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="HTML5App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">
    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid that contains the content of the page-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="Browser"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Loaded="Browser_Loaded"
                          NavigationFailed="Browser_NavigationFailed"/>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/html/css/phone.css" />
        <title>Windows Phone 8.1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>APPLICATION</p>
        </div>
        <div id="page-title">
            <p>page title</p>
        </div>
        <select>
            <option>Foo</option>
            <option>Bar</option>
            <option>A string too long to be read into this component</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please share your relevant code?

Comment: Updated with code, thank you.